# How to get chunk data using WebRTC in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I have file sharing code on CodePen: https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/yvMeRg?editors=1010

It works fine in Chrome, but don't in FireFox because If I send text file over WebRTC firefox get message as string and in Chrome it get blob data.

Here is main chunk for the code:

```
var message_callback = (function() {
  var buf, count, meta;

  return function onmessage(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (typeof event.data === 'string') {
      meta = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log({meta: meta.length})
      buf = window.buf = new Uint8ClampedArray(meta.length);
      count = 0;
      log('Expecting a total of ' + buf.byteLength + ' bytes');
      return;
    }

    var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(event.data);
    buf.set(data, count);
    count += (data.byteLength || event.data.size);

    if (count === buf.byteLength) {
      // we're done: all data chunks have been received
      log('Done. downloading.');
      new FileHandler(meta.filename, buf.buffer).save();
    }
  };
})();
function FileHandler(filename, arrayBuffer) {
  this.filename = filename;
  this.arraybuffer = arrayBuffer;
}
FileHandler.prototype.save = function() {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.href = this.dataURI(this.arraybuffer);
  link.download = this.filename;
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};
FileHandler.prototype.dataURI = function(blob) {
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
```

Everything else is working except receiving data in message function and saving it into a file.

This works fine in Chrome but in Firefox it save `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` into the file (as seen in Emacs). I've tried to convert arraybuffer in `dataURI` because it's not blob that is passing to that function, with no success.

**Note**: demo works only with two computers if more users will visit it and try to send files it will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has long been [incompliant with the specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-datachannel-binarytype). The easiest workaround is to set the datachannel.binaryType to 'arraybuffer' which is supported by all browsers supporting datachannel.

I *think* it is sufficient to do this on the senders side after createDataChannel.

Comment: Thanks it works, much better then my answer.